# Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator for a positive definite kernel is positive

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-transforms

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $k \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable [positive-definite kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) such that $\int_{X} \int_X k^2(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(y) < \infty$. Then it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) that the operator $T \colon L^2(\mu) \to L^2(\mu)$ defined by
$$
Tf(x) := \int_X k(x,y) f(y) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$
is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

Since $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$, it is easy to see from Fubini's theorem that
$$
\langle Tf, g \rangle = \int_X \left( \int_X k(x,y) f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(y) \right) g(x) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x) = \int_X \left( \int_X k(y,x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x) \right) f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(y) = \langle f, Tg \rangle
$$
and hence $T$ is self-adjoint.

**How do I show that $T$ is positive?**

That is, I want to show that for every $f \in L^2(\mu)$
$$
\langle Tf, f \rangle = \int_X \left( \int_X k(x,y) f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(y) \right) f(x) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x) \ge 0
$$

We need to somehow use the positive-definiteness of $k$, but I am unable to do that unless I assume $\mu$ is something simple like a counting measure. Ultimately, I want to be able to say that the eigenvalues of $T$ are such that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots > 0$.

Comment: Have you tried something invoking the spectral theorem? Anyway, I think that what you are looking for is exactly [Mercer-s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer's_theorem)

Comment: Spectral theorem can be applied ($T$ is compact and self-adjoint) but it doesn't help here since it only says $|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \cdots > 0$ and $\lambda_i \to 0$, and nothing about positivity.

Comment: But you are right about Mercer's theorem. It does come very close to what I want. But it assumes continuity of $k$ and $X$ to be a compact Hausdorff space. I wonder if we can't do better than that.